# How to establish associations using FactoryGirl to test a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm just beginning to experiment with Rails tests. I'm having trouble getting started.

My first tests require a User, which I'm creating within FactoryGirl. But my model validates presence of an invitation.

```
class User
  has_many :sent_invitations, :class_name => 'Invitation', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :invitation
  validates_presence_of :invitation_id
end

class Invitation
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  has_one :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

How do I generate an invited user using FactoryGirl?

I've tried a few approaches, but the association is not being set. The one that seems most likely to work is something like:

```
factory :invitation do
  token "MyInvitationToken"
  recipient_email "test@example.com"

  factory :invited_user do
    association :user, :factory => :user
  end
end

factory :user do
  email "test@example.com"
end
```

This is failing with `Validation failed: Invitation is required`.

What is the correct way to establish this association with FactoryGirl?

For bonus points, how can I modify this so the :invitation.recipient_email is a sequence `sequence(:recipient_email) { |n| "test#{n}@example.com" }`, and that this value gets passed to the invited_user's email column for each iteration.

Comment: http://rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
factory :user do
  email "test@example.com"
  f.association :invitation
end
```

OR

```
factory :user do
  email "test@example.com"

  after_build do |foo|
    user.invitations << Factory.build(:invitation)
  end
end
```

Comment: ok, now I feel silly. Of course the association should be nested under User. Thanks! But two questions: (1) why f.association? I've not seen that in any docs. (2) is it possible to pass the user's generated email to the invitation, so that a sequence can be used?

Comment: @AndyHarvey just `association` is fine... the `f.` is not needed.